# Como juntar resultado de duas tabelas 1 - n

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte problema.

1 tabela cliente que possui relação com 1 tabela fotos (respectivas fotos do cliente)

relação 1 cliente para "n" fotos;

> Resumindo:
>
> cliente possui **id, nome.**
>
> foto possui **cliente_id, conteudo** *(bytes).*

Não consigo fazer uma query que busque todos os clientes mas quero apenas **uma foto** de cada cliente

Preciso que o select retorne isso de cada cliente:

**RESULTADO QUE ESPERO:**

```
cliente.id, 
cliente.nome, 
foto.conteudo //uma foto para cada cliente.
```

**PORQUE?**
  Estou fazendo uma lista de clientes que mostre apenas a foto e o nome na pagina inicial.

Comment: Uma foto, mas qual? Qualquer uma?

Comment: qualquer uma da outra tabela, mas tem que ser uma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode agrupar o resultado por cliente:

```
SELECT
    cliente.id, cliente.nome, foto.conteudo
FROM cliente
    LEFT JOIN foto /* use INNER JOIN se todo cliente tiver 1+ foto */
    ON foto.cliente_id = cliente.id
GROUP BY cliente.id
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou. Me pode explicar o por que está retornando apenas uma foto ?

Comment: Quando você usa `GROUP BY`, garante uma linha para cada item que mandou agrupar (no caso, `cliente.id`). Você pode inclusive incluir `COUNT(*)` no select para saber quantas fotos tem por cliente. Só que não existe lógica para o mysql escolher qual foto virá. Se você tiver um critério pra isso, a query já fica mais complicada (requer uma subquery).

Comment: Ok faltei algumas aulas de Banco de Dados, obrigado pela solução e explicação @bfavaretto.

Comment: @JuarezA.FrancoJunior Talvez você não aprendesse isso na aula de banco de dados porque não é um comportamento padrão SQL e sim um truque do MySql. A maioria dos bancos exige no GROUP BY todas as colunas do SELECT onde não seja utilizada função de agregação.